# Many2many field odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How define Many2many field for res.users in odoo 9.

I need select more than one user in field!

```
users_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
users_ids = fields.Many2many('res.users', 'user_project_rel', 'user_id', 'project_id', string='Users')

<field name="users_ids" widget="many2many_tags" />
```

res.users  -  model

user_project_rel - new table

user_id - id of user in new table

project_id - id of project or any other module in new table

Answer (score 3):

You can find a lot of information about fields here https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html

In your case, you need this.

class openerp.fields.Many2many(comodel_name=None, relation=None, column1=None, column2=None, string=None, **kwargs)

Bases: openerp.fields._RelationalMulti

Many2many field; the value of such a field is the recordset.

Parameters

- comodel_name -- name of the target model (string)

The attribute comodel_name is mandatory except in the case of related fields or field extensions.

Parameters

- relation -- optional name of the table that stores the relation in
  the database (string)
- column1 -- optional name of the column referring to "these" records
  in the table relation (string)
- column2 -- optional name of the column referring to "those" records
  in the table relation (string)

The attributes relation, column1 and column2 are optional. If not given, names are automatically generated from model names, provided model_name and comodel_name are different!

Parameters
domain -- an optional domain to set on candidate values on the client side (domain or string)

- context -- an optional context to use on the client side when
  handling that field (dictionary)
- limit -- optional limit to use upon read (integer)